# fprintf() within a subprogram

Tags: c, function, file-io

Im stuck when trying to write to my file within my subprogram.

```
void new_page(float *a, float *b, float *c, int *d){
    fprintf(results,"\nPage Totals: %f\t%f\t%f\t%d", *a,*b,*c,*d);
}
```

I get a warning saying

```
Warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'fprinf' [enabled by default]
```

> "error: 'results' undeclared (first use in this function)"

in main fprintf works fine, its just when it comes to the subprogram/function it wont work. from my understanding it thinks that results is undeclared, so do i have to pass the name or location of the file to make it work?

Comment: About the warning.. did you mean `fprintf()`? and error:where `results´ is declared? Can you give more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `results` is global, it is undefined.

From the looks of it, you have opened a file (stream) as `results` in main. If so it only exists in the scope of main.

Pass it along to the function. Do not recommend to make it global.

---

It would look like:

```
void new_page(FILE *results,  float *a, float *b, float *c, int *d){
    fprintf(results,"\nPage Totals: %f\t%f\t%f\t%d", *a,*b,*c,*d);
}
```

---

Also; if you have this function in a separate file then `main()`, where, as you say `fprintf` works - you have to include `stdio.h` in that file as well.

---

Edit: Sounds like you are doing something wrong with that function signature and prototype etc.

As a simple example (without needed checks on fopen etc):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(FILE * fp)
{
    fprintf(fp, "HELLO\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("blabla", "w");
    foo(fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Also; you say your compiler is not complaining. Are you using extensive warnings? If not you should. Ie GCC:

> $ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o my_prog my_source.c

I usually also add `-std=c89`, or if needed, `-std=c99`.

Then run it wit valgrind:

> $ valgrind ./my_prog

These two steps will give you lots of hints and clues to where things could be wrong.

Comment: So to pass it i would just pass a pointer to the file in the parameter list and it should see that it is defined? Oh and its not global, im not using any global variables.

Comment: Yes, sort of. When you pass it like that you tell the function; "Hello, here is an address, and at that address you'll find a FILE stream".

Comment: the function is in a separate file. ill try again and see what the deal is :D

Comment: figured it out. for the function prototype i had to use FILE** and in the actual function i just used FILE*. I guess since the file is already being pointed to i had to use a double pointer. It is C so who knows what will happen, just because it doesnt give errors doesnt mean it will work haha

Comment: turns out it doesnt work :/ the compiler isnt complaining anymore because the parameters match but it doesnt print to the file. I put a printf to show to the screen that im in the function and it prints out my text.

Comment: running valgrind shows i dont have any errors. shows no leaks as well

Comment: Hmm oh well, ill ask my teacher tomorrow about it and see what he says. Thank you alot for your help, i really appreciate it!

Comment: So I figured it out, I just left the function prototype blank to tell the compiler to trust me on what I'm sending. As the function its self, i just passed a pointer and it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

To solve the `fprintf` warning, you need to add

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

near the top of your source file.

The `results` error is different; you can either make it global or pass it as an argument to your `new_page` function.

Making a variable global (i.e., defining outside any function, including `main`) is generally poor style, but if `results` is a `FILE*` that you're going to be using throughout your program, it's not unreasonable to make it global.

Comment: As far as global variables im not allowed to use any at all for the program. Like you said it's poor style and my teacher said it's frowned upon to use globals.

Comment: @sergio: Then you'll need to pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There ara more than one solutions here.

1. You can pass the file handler to the function.
2. You can use printf to write into a file. But if you do that you cannot write to the screen again. Search freopen